# Push live updates to client through Django Channels & Websockets

Tags: javascript, django, python-2.7, django-channels, channel

I'm trying to make a page which shows live-updating data to the client. The rest of the site is built with Django, so I'm trying to use Channels for this.

The data I am displaying is saved in both a JSON file and a MySQL database for further calculations in other parts of the site. Ideally, **I would like to display the latest data received (that is, when the file updates) to the client as it is received.**

And even though as I understand Channels are built exactly for this purpose, I am having trouble doing it.

I have tried sending multiple requests from the client-side with delay and loops in the consumer, but it either (ironically) only updates on refresh or updates instantly. However, neither of these approaches are triggered by a change in the file or database.

This is the code that "works", but doesn't really do what's required. (also, admittedly, there's basically nothing there...)

```
# consumers.py
def ws_connect(message):
  message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})

def ws_receive(message):

  with open("data.json") as jsonfile:
    jsondata = json.load(jsonfile)

  res = json.dumps(jsondata)
  message.reply_channel.send({ "text": res, })

#routing.py
from channels.routing import route
from .consumers import ws_receive, ws_connect


channel_routing = [
  route("websocket.receive", ws_receive, path=r"^/websockets/$"),
  route("websocket.connect", ws_connect, path=r"^/websockets/$"),
]
```

JS used:

```
<script>
var wsurl = "ws://" + "mywebsite.com" + "/websockets/";
socket = new WebSocket(wsurl);

socket.onopen = function() {
     socket.send("this is a request");
     console.log('sent');
  }

socket.onmessage = function(message) {
    console.log(message.data);
    document.getElementById("livedata").innerHTML = message.data;
}
</script>
```

I'd be perfectly happy with a link to the docs that would help me achieve something like this, as I've managed to not find the solution for a whole week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add user to django channels Group on ws_connect

```
from channels.auth import channel_session_user_from_http
from channels import Group

@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message, **kwargs):
    http_user = message.user
    if not http_user.is_anonymous:
        message.reply_channel.send({'accept': True})
        Group('user-'+str(http_user.id)).add(message.reply_channel)`
```

send any new updates data to the user by

```
Group('user-1').send({'text': 'hello user 1'})
Group('user-2').send({'text': 'hello user 2'})
```

Comment: Doesn't this just add Groups to the equation for traffic management? My main issue is finding a way to send new data from a file when it gets updated.

Comment: You have to use pynotify  https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify to watch a file for change.

Comment: @Roxerg: `channels` are not meant to be watching files for you. Implement a file watcher that calls `Group('user-1').send({'text': 'file changes here'})` and you are good to go. Do the same call in a django signal receiver on a db change emit if you want to send db changes. The answer should be the accepted one as there is nothing to add in my opinion.

Comment: @hoefling Can that file watcher be a separate script? That is, can I send messages to the group outside of the consumers.py?

Comment: @Roxerg: sure, the only requirement is to know the group name you want to broadcast to. From anywhere in your code: `from channels import Group; Group('user-1').send({'text': 'what I have to say you'})`.