# Django Channels - Client receives only one message when Group.send() is called in a loop in consumers.py

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have built a Django app which runs automated testing. I collect the inputs from the user, as to what all tests need to be run and when the user clicks on submit button, the tests run for a few hours to a couple of days (depending on the number of tests selected) and once all the tests are completed, the results are showed on a template.

Now the problem is, till all the tests are completed, the user is not updated with the progress. So I decided to use Django Channles to provide live update to the client as and when I have results for individual tests.

With my implementation, I call the Group('user-1').send({'text': i}) method in a for loop. But all I see in the template is only the output of the last Group('user-1').send({'text': i}) operation.

As per my requirement, once Group('user-1').send({'text': i}) is called, the socket.onmessage()  function in the  section of my template should receive the message and should again wait for messages sent by subsequent Group('user-1').send({'text': i}) calls.

I saw a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287849/push-live-updates-to-client-through-django-channels-websockets) which is already answered, but the solution is not working for me. Please help me identify what needs to corrected in my code, shown below.

```
consumers.py
------------
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message, **kwargs):
    http_user = message.user
    if not http_user.is_anonymous:
        message.reply_channel.send({'accept': True})
        Group('user-'+str(http_user.id)).add(message.reply_channel)

def ws_message(message):
    for i in my_results_list:
        Group('user-1').send({'text': i})
        sleep(1)

results.html
------------

 <script>
    // Note that the path doesn't matter for routing; any WebSocket
    // connection gets bumped over to WebSocket consumers

    socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/task/summary/");

    socket.onopen = function() {
        socket.send("Hello");
    }

    socket.onmessage = function(message) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = message.data;
    }

    socket.onmessage()

    // Call onopen directly if socket is already open
    // if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) socket.onopen();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = message.data;` this overwrites the content of demo each time it is called. You want something like:

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += message.data`
or
`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<br />' + message.data`

If this answer solves your problem please mark it correct.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it is now showing all items of the my_results_list, but there is a problem, all the items gets displayed at once. I need the template to display each item incrementally, as and when Group('user-1').send({'text': i}) is called and not all at once. The whole purpose of using Django channels is to get live updates.

Comment: This only happens in the old version of Django channels. You should really switch to the new version because Channels 1 is no longer supported. If you want it to show up immediately you need to do `Group('user-1').send({'text': i}, immediately=True)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding immediately=True in channels==1.1.8 solved my problem. I cannot upgrade to channels 2 as it requires python 3.x version. I will consider upgrading to python 3.x at some later point of time.